# divisor sum of a product, excluding divisors of its terms

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking for an efficient way to determine the sum of divisors of a product, counting only those that are not divisors of its terms: $$M(p,q)=\sum_{\large d \mid pq,\: d \nmid p,\: d \nmid q}{d}$$

For example, $M(4,9)$ would yield $72$. $\quad(6+12+18+36=72,\;$ as we would not count $1,2,3,4,9).$

Is it possible to find that without factorization?
Can it be found efficiently for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{M(i,p)}$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n {M(i,j)} $?

Comment: I guess you intended to require the terms in the product in $M$ to be coprime? Because $M(6\times 6)$ turns out differently than $M(4\times 9)$...

Comment: Good point, I just forgot about that. However, the terms are given and not restricted to be coprime, so I should have written $M(p,q)$. $M(4,9)=72$ and $M(6,6)=79$ will be different indeed. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: The edit making it a function of two variables resolves this well :)